# Build multiple SSIS projects (.dtproj) with ADO pipeline

Tags: ssis, yaml, pipeline, ado

Hello everyone (i realy need help on this one)
The main goad is to build several SSIS projects (.dtproj) which is in the same repository as the yaml files, basically I have 3 files which look like this:
1 -  main yaml

```
trigger:
- none
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
  - powershell: |
      # PowerShell script goes here
      $projectFile = "SSIS/project_paths.txt"
      $projects = Get-Content $projectFile -Raw
      $projectList = $projects -split "`n" | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
      
      # Set the parameter name
      $parameterName = "MyParameter"

      $formattedProjects = $projectList | ForEach-Object { "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$parameterName;issecret=false]$_" }

      # Print each item in the list
      $projectList | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
    displayName: 'Set Pipeline Parameter and Print'

  - template: CI/template.yaml
    parameters:
      projects: $projectList
```

2 - yaml templates

````
parameters:
  - name: projects
    type: object

steps: 
     
- ${{ each projectPath in parameters.projects }}:
  - task: SSIS.ssis-devops-tools.ssis-build-task.SSISBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build SSIS for ${{ projectPath }}'
    inputs:
      projectPath: ${{ projectPath }}
      stripSensitive: true
      outputPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      continueOnError: true  # Continue building even if some projects fail (optional)

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Build Artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'YourArtifactName'
    publishLocation: 'Container'```

3 - text file
````

Projectpath1
Projectpath2

```
the goal is to launch the main pipeline which will read the project paths from the text file then the store in a parameter then launch the template with the list of project paths and loop over the build task but i always got an error in the build section ! what i'm trying to do is correct ? or is technicaly impossible?

chatgpt didnt help me that much :p
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @geekZ Did you get this resolved? What is the error you are getting in the build section? I have a similar set up whereby in a yaml file I have a list of dtproj files. This list is passed into a main yaml file which in the first stage loops over the projects building each via template yaml file, then publishes them all. The following stages deploy to different environments (this is made of two templates, one for the environment and then one for the packages). Happy to share if still required.